# Time complexity of converting std::string to std::string_view

Tags: c++, string, string-view

Minimal Reproducible example:

```
using namespace std;

#include<string>
#include<string_view>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    string s = "someString";
    string_view sV = string_view(s);
    string_view sVTwo = string_view(begin(s), end(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Is the time complexity of creating the string_view sV linear relative to the number of chars in the string s or is it irrelevant how long the string s is? Likewise, is the time complexity of the construction of sVTwo linear or constant depending on how many chars are in the string?

The reason I am confused is I cannot tell which of these constructors here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view is being used to construct the string.

Comment: Doesn't the link state that the complexity is constant?  A `std::string` knows its own length since it has a `const` `size()` function.  It's when a raw `char *` is used where the length of the string comes into play, since a character pointer knows nothing about the length of the string, and must iterate until a null is reached.

Comment: It's not using any of the `string_view` constructors. It's using the "[`string` to `string_view`" conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view).

Comment: Protip: never put `using namespace std;` above `#include` directives, and ideally never use `using namespace`, instead import specific type-names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the time complexity of creating the string_view sV linear relative
> to the number of chars in the string s or is it irrelevant how long
> the string s is?

`string_view(s)` will call the `string`'s [`operator std::string_view()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view), which is equivalent to `return string_view(data(), size())`, and since `string`'s `data()` and `size()` are both `O(1)`, so the complexity has nothing to do with the length of the string.

> Likewise, is the time complexity of the construction of sVTwo linear
> or constant depending on how many chars are in the string?

It will call `string_view(It first, End last)` and use [`std::to_address(first)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address) and `last - first` to initialize the `string_view`'s member variables. Since the former and pointer arithmetic are both constant time, this is also constant time. Please note that this function was introduced in C++20, and calling `string_view(begin(s), end(s))` in C++17 is ill-formed.